# gcc make dependency and object simultaneously

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++

I am using gcc 4.8.2, and I am trying to build both the object file and the dependency file concurrently.

This works:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -MP -MD -c foo.cxx -o foo.o
$ [ -s foo.d ] && [ -s foo.o ] && echo yay
yay
```

However, instead of generating `foo.d`, I want to generate `foo.D`, so I tried:

```
$ rm foo.d foo.o
$ g++ -std=c++11 -MP -M -MF foo.D -c foo.cxx -o foo.o
$ [ -s foo.D ] && [ -s foo.o ] && echo yay
$
```

That successfully generates `foo.D`, but makes an empty `foo.o`. Why? The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) for `-MD` starts with:

> -MD is equivalent to -M -MF *file*, except that -E is not implied.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `-MF foo.D` to the original call?

Comment: @EtanReisner Nope! Guess that's the answer :) Didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: @EtanReisner Want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The docs for `-MF` explicitly mention it that's why I suggested it. I'm not sure why `-M -MF` doesn't work though. That strikes me as odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `-M -MF foo.D` isn't working for you my reading of the documentation is the same as yours. I think it should be working. An `strace` of the compilation might tell you something interesting about what is going on.

But as a solution you can just add the `-MF foo.D` argument to the original command line and that should do what you want.

As the documentation for `-MF` says:

> -MF file
>   When used with -M or -MM, specifies a file to write the dependencies to. If no -MF switch is given the preprocessor sends the rules to the same place it would have sent preprocessed output
>
> When used with the driver options -MD or -MMD, -MF overrides the default dependency output file.